# FirebaseMessagingService OnNewToken() is Called Before Android OnCreate(), Causing Failed to Keep Token on DeviceInstallationService

Tags: xamarin.forms, push-notification, azure-notificationhub

I have implement Push Notification on Xamarin Forms using Azure Notification Hubs. But the problem is when OnNewToken() on FirebaseMessagingService fired, IDeviceInstallationService havent registered yet. So when keep the new token causing exception.
IDeviceInstallationService is initialize on Oncreate() MainActivity.

So, how to Called OnCreate() to register first, after that get new token on FirebaseMessagingService

Comment: Did you try to  create a application,and initialize on its `OnCreate()` method.

Comment: A couple of questions, are you registering your own FirebaseMessagingService? And which version of the Xamarin Android Notification Hubs bindings are you using?